Chrome suddenly rendering font darker
I restarted my computer and now Chrome is rendering font darker. How can I change the font back to how it was before?

I was working in Fontforge and created an error there. Could that cause font to render differently in Chrome on various websites (like this one)? How do I fix this?

I see no difference between the two images in your question. You're going to have to be more detailed in your description of the problem.

Did you compare the rendering of a standard font in both versions? Feels like that would answer most of your question.

Tangentially Perpendicular - look closely at the pixels.
Robby - I can't compare a standard font because I don't have any screenshots of what Chrome looked like before in other fonts - I only have screenshots of my font (pictured above). Even the font here on stackoverflow looks darker

If you're running on windows you may try adjust the cleartype settings. Maybe the subpixel rendering has changed due to a system update applied on restart. All in all there is no way to get a 100% consistent rendering across all browsers or OS
